# Can't use tzset with "use strict"

Tags: perl, localtime

I need to get current time with my specified timezone, so I'm using `tzset`. But when I add `use strict`, I get the following error

```
use strict;

use POSIX qw(tzset);

......................

sub is_active
{
    tzset;
    $ENV{TZ} = 'America/New_York';

    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
    if (($hour > 9 && $min > 30) || ($hour < 14))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

Bareword "tzset" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at .......
```

Is this known issue? Is there any alternative I can use?

Comment: The code you show doesn't produce any messages, neither warnings nor errors. The source of the problem must be in the code you don't show.

Comment: I see, updated.

Comment: Now I get `Undefined subroutine &my_module::tzset called at ...`

Comment: Is there by any chance a `package` declaration within the code you didn't show, somewhere after the `use POSIX qw(tzset)`?

Comment: Yes, there is, right after `use POSIX qw(tzset)`, should I take it at the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import subroutines from a module like `use POSIX qw(tzset)`, the imported subroutines are imported into the *current package*. If you do not declare a package, that is the `main` package.

To fix your problem, first declare a `package`, then `use` any modules you need:

```
use strict;

package MyModule;
use POSIX qw(tzset);  # now tzset is available within MyModule

...
```

For pragmas like `use strict` and `use warnings` that change how your code behaves but don't import any subroutines, it is not important whether they come before or after a package declaration. Their effect is not limited to a package but to a lexical scope (delimited by curly braces).